How to deploy a frontend React Router App with a NodeJS backend on Render
I deployed my project on render.com and my app is live at this link https://react-router-events-j6yu.onrender.com/
However, when I go to an URL with /events, the UI disappears and the page displays as follows:
// 20240523233320
// https://react-router-events-j6yu.onrender.com/events/55b79b2e-902f-44b1-b292-08ab669b76c6

{
  "event": {
    "title": "Test again...",
    "image": "https://www.meydanfz.ae/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Events-1024x576.png",
    "date": "2024-06-08",
    "description": "Test",
    "id": "55b79b2e-902f-44b1-b292-08ab669b76c6"
  }
}

It renders JSON data instead of HTML.
I contacted the Render's support and they said that it might be that this is an application issue and not a render-specific issue.
Indeed, I created a "Web service" on render to host both my backend & my frontend apps at the same time.
I think the configuration is correct on Render.
So, I show you some of my code here so that you might detect the error hopefully.
La structure de mon projet est la suivante:
/my-project
  /backend
    app.js
    events.json
    /data
      events.js
    /routes
      events.js
    /util
      error.js
      validation.js
  /frontend
    /build
      index.html
      // other build files
    src
      // my React source files


backend\app.js:

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const eventRoutes = require('./routes/events');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

// Serve static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));

// API routes
app.use('/events', eventRoutes);

// The "catchall" handler: for any request that doesn't match one above, send back React's index.html file.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Serving index.html for request:', req.url);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build', 'index.html'));
});

// Error handling middleware
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  const status = error.status || 500;
  const message = error.message || 'Something went wrong.';
  res.status(status).json({ message: message });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


backend\data\event.js:

const fs = require('node:fs/promises');
const path = require('path');
const { v4: generateId } = require('uuid');
const { NotFoundError } = require('../util/errors');

// Utilisation de path.resolve pour garantir le bon chemin d'accès
const dataFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../events.json');

async function readData() {
  try {
    console.log('Reading data from:', dataFilePath); // Ajout de log pour vérifier le chemin
    const data = await fs.readFile(dataFilePath, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to read data:', error);
    throw new Error('Could not read events data.');
  }
}

async function writeData(data) {
  try {
    console.log('Writing data to:', dataFilePath); // Ajout de log pour vérifier le chemin
    await fs.writeFile(dataFilePath, JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to write data:', error);
    throw new Error('Could not write events data.');
  }
}

async function getAll() {
  const storedData = await readData();
  if (!storedData.events) {
    throw new NotFoundError('Could not find any events.');
  }
  return storedData.events;
}

async function get(id) {
  const storedData = await readData();
  if (!storedData.events || storedData.events.length === 0) {
    throw new NotFoundError('Could not find any events.');
  }

  const event = storedData.events.find(ev => ev.id === id);
  if (!event) {
    throw new NotFoundError('Could not find event for id ' + id);
  }

  return event;
}

async function add(data) {
  const storedData = await readData();
  storedData.events.unshift({ ...data, id: generateId() });
  await writeData(storedData);
}

async function replace(id, data) {
  const storedData = await readData();
  if (!storedData.events || storedData.events.length === 0) {
    throw new NotFoundError('Could not find any events.');
  }

  const index = storedData.events.findIndex(ev => ev.id === id);
  if (index < 0) {
    throw new NotFoundError('Could not find event for id ' + id);
  }

  storedData.events[index] = { ...data, id };

  await writeData(storedData);
}

async function remove(id) {
  const storedData = await readData();
  const updatedData = storedData.events.filter(ev => ev.id !== id);
  await writeData({ events: updatedData });
}

exports.getAll = getAll;
exports.get = get;
exports.add = add;
exports.replace = replace;
exports.remove = remove;

I can give you more detail if needed.

it worked normally for me though, did you try to access the url directly? can you provide the react code? maybe your git repo link?

What do you mean it worked normally for you though? When you click on the "Events" navigation link and then you refresh the page, what do you see?
Yes, I tried to access this URL https://react-router-events-j6yu.onrender.com/events directly and I get the same JSON data.
Here is my React code via my GitHub repo link: https://github.com/sofiane-abou-abderrahim/react-router-events/tree/test.
Please use the "test" branch.

This is most definitely an application issue and not an uncorrect configuration on Render.
Indeed, what's happening here is a mix up around client side routing and server paths.
When you're browsing the site and clicking on the "Events" navigation link, that's not really loading /events from the server - it's the React Router changing address to make it look like it's that path and then your JS is fetching /events from the server.
When you refresh, you are telling the browser to load from /events - which is the path you have your JSON loading from.
To resolve, you should update the server path /events (https://github.com/sofiane-abou-abderrahim/react-router-events/blob/test/backend/app.js#L21) to be something like /data and then update your JS to fetch from /data. (https://github.com/sofiane-abou-abderrahim/react-router-events/blob/test/frontend/src/pages/Events.js#L21)
That way, clicking on "Events", will change the browser to /events and load the data from /data, a refresh means your "* catch all path in server" would redirect and React Router handle it.
